# Find all my contributions including issues

Tags: github

Is there any way to find all interactions between 2 users? For e.g. Here are 2 users...

https://github.com/kavgan

https://github.com/shantanuo

I remember that I have raised an issue in one of repos of the user "kavgan". But is there a way to find that? What I expect is this...

https://github.com/kavgan/nlp-in-practice/issues/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter in an issue search for a given repository, as described in [this article](https://ardalis.com/show-all-github-issues-assigned-to-me/)

```
is:issue author:shantanuo
```

See the [results here](https://github.com/kavgan/nlp-in-practice/search?q=is%3Aissue%20author%3Ashantanuo&type=Issues).

But to apply the same to all repositories, you would need a [graphql query](https://developer.github.com/v4/input_object/issuefilters/), similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49136171/6309).